# Tool bar in editor missing in WP

Tags: editor, localization

I am having somewhat amazing problem. My client is in sweden.

When I check the site from my country (Nepal), everything is fine. But tool in editor in wordpress panel is missing in sweden. I checked with teamwork and remote desktop. And he was right. And tool bar is missing in all browsers ( i checked in firefox , safari and chrome)

And this is problem in current project only. My other projects in WP is working fine.

So getting crazy..

I have disabled all plugins, update wordpress to latest verion 3.4. And still the problem exists. Please kindly help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean the WordPress Admin bar which shows in the header of the logged in user page?

Can you get the user to login and check that they haven't disabled this under the User > My Profile menu option

Also you might like to check out this plugin which allows you to switch between users so you can check this with out using Remote Desktop etc

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-switching/

Hope that helps?

Damien